# Why are my functions not found?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Js file with some functions, but now the problem occurs that some functions are not found by earlier functions in the js file.
like you can see on the image I attached the line with the square should call the function below him but that is not working.
This is not the first time I have this problem but normally I just move with the functions and than they work.

Can somebody explain me how to fix because it is really annoying because I find moving functions not a good solution.

If you need the entire code click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e4s25a64/3/). You need to start with the `mapGen` function.

**edit: all the code is now in the jsFiddle**

[image]

Comment: Your jsfiddle seems to miss a lot of things. I can't run the code. The image doesn't reveal any obvious errors.

Comment: @FelixKling I did that because you doesn't need all the code. only the code in the js file is needed

Comment: Javascript is executed line by line, therefore your functions should be declared BEFORE being called. Also, if you're using jQuery, don't forget the $(document).ready.

Comment: @briosheje Functions are supposed to be hoisted.

Comment: Well, if we can't run the code to reproduce the error, how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: Fiddle is missing jquery, once added, it produces no result or errors

Comment: @Scimonster: In his case, by not calling anything when the DOM is ready, he must do that, unless he calls the functions once everything has been loaded, doesn't he? :) PS: I'm working on the fiddle, that's where I took the informations from

Comment: @Huangism After adding jQuery and rerunning the code, my console starts filling with output after a moment. But OP's code in question is never hit (tried with several breakpoints).

Comment: @Vinc199789 what is the error you get? Where is the code placed? in `<head>` or document ready or on load?

Comment: Also, the function newBuilding() is missing in the fiddle. --> http://prntscr.com/647yym . However, the script runs fine after a while due to the setTimeout. ----> http://jsfiddle.net/e4s25a64/4/

Comment: @ajp15243 ok I see the console outputs but no error

Comment: You did not give us enouth details. But in your fiddle you have a variable var buildings = 0; with the same name of the function you are calling. try to change it

Comment: here is the http://jsfiddle.net/e4s25a64/6/. The edit I made to the questions didn't take the new jsfiddle so here it is with all the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error at `buildings()` is

> Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function

(in Chrome)

You have

```
var buildings = 0;
```

and

```
function buildings() { ... }
```

You can't use the same variable for two different things.

(because of hoisting, the variable initialization overrides the function)

Comment: @Vinc199789: Different browsers produce different error messages.

Comment: Solved. You were right but the console didn't saw it a a problem. I changed the var buildings to buildings_amount and now it works. Thanks